# Automatically reset timer when the current item of view pager is last page

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I want to implement an image slider with viewpager. The slider should automatically scroll horizontally. So I use a timer as below:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES-1) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer = new Timer();
                }
                mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };

        timer = new Timer(); // This will create a new Thread
        timer .schedule(new TimerTask() { // task to be scheduled

            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 500, 3000);
```

`mPager` is the viewpager which already has been set.

The problem is that when it reaches the last item (image), it stops there and doesn't scroll anymore. Another thing, when I scroll it manually to the first page, it **suddenly** scrolls to the last page ignorant of timer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After reaching the last image, you want to start again with the 1st image or it should loop back one by one..?

Comment: No difference. Any solution which is solved my problem is considered :) @MuthukrishnanRajendran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        int currentPage = mPager.getCurrentItem();
        if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES-1) {
            currentPage = 0;
        } else {
            currentPage++;
        }
        mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage, true);

        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(Update, 500);
```

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. The second problem is solved. But the first one is not solved still. I mean that the slider reaches the last item and it won't swipe anymore. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You mean it's not moving to the first item..?

Comment: Yes, It's like that. I just do the same as you say. @MuthukrishnanRajendran

Comment: To be more specific, I use `mPager` in a fragment and it has an adapter which holds the image items.

Comment: What about timer? Is it not needed?

Comment: handler.postDelayed(this, 5000); this will take care of timer part, but you can declare handler globally and remove the runnable on pause of your fragment

Comment: Thank you so much, now all the things go well :) @MuthukrishnanRajendran